# how to applay 2d mask on 1d array

Tags: python, numpy

What is the best way to apply a 2d mask on a 1d array? let's say we have the array a of the shape (k, n) the array b of shape (k, 1) and a mask of shape (k, n)
I want to compute

```
c = np.zeros_like(a)
for i in range(a.shape[1]):
    c[mask[:, i], i] = a[mask[:, i], i] - b[mask[:, i]]
```

is there a more efficient way than use `np.repat`?

```
c[mask] = a[mask] - np.repeat(b, a.shape[1], axis=1)[mask]
```

for example:

```
a = np.arange(25).reshape(5, 5)
b = np.ones((5, 1))
mask = np.random.randint(0, 2, (5, 5), dtype=np.bool)
c = np.zeros_like(a)
c[mask] = a[mask] - np.repeat(b, a.shape[1], 1)[mask]
```

Comment: Still somewhat problematic since b can't be masked either.

Comment: i have edited to c=np.zeros_like(a), thanks.

Comment: Oh... is that the question? You can use `np.broadcast_to(b, mask.shape)[mask]`, which should consume no additional memory. idk about efficiency, though: it's not any more efficient than `np.repeat`; for exploiting sparsity, you'd probably need to use something more powerful than numpy.

Comment: Please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

The way how you initialize `c` array is out of question.

Then, to perform your "selective" substitution, run:

```
c = np.where(mask, a - b, c)
```

Details:

- `a - b` - Subtract `b` from each column of `a`. For the time being,
  with no mask.
- `np.where(...)` - Take values from `a - b`, but only elements "indicated"
  by *True* values in the mask. Other elements take from `c`.
- `c = ...` - Save the result back in `c`.

This way the mask is applied to **2-D** arrays:

- original `c` array,
- and a temporary array, created by subtraction of **broadcasted** `b`
  array form `a`.